# Django Rest Framework get_field is not being called

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I've got an existing Django code base which uses Django Rest Framework to expose the data. I had one field which was defined as a `SerializerMethodField()` in the Serializer:

```
categories = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
```

And in the same serializer this get_method is defined:

```
def get_categories(self, obj):
    return [obj.categories.choices[key.upper()] for key in obj.categories]
```

That worked, but I had to add a way to also let users post new data to the api. In the model the field is defined as a MultiSelectField:

```
categories = MultiSelectField( choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=64, max_choices=6, null=True, blank=True)
```

Since the `SerializerMethodField` is read-only by definition I changed the field to a `CharField` (because it's a varchar in the DB):

```
categories = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, max_length=100)
```

That works for posting new content, but unfortunately, the `get_categories()` is not being called anymore.

Does anybody know how I can make it call the `get_categories()` method while keeping the `CharField`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that is the underlying issue that's affecting you, but I guess you could be using a `ChoiceField` instead.

Like, create the class:

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class ChoicesField(serializers.Field):
    def __init__(self, choices, **kwargs):
        self._choices = choices
        super(ChoicesField, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return self._choices[obj]

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return getattr(self._choices, data)
```

and then use it like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = Choices(
        ('A', 'CategoryA', 'CategoryA'),
        ('B', 'CategoryB', 'CategoryB')
    )

category = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually, the field is defined as a `MultiSelectField()` in the model (I added that info to the question). Do you have suggestions in this situation?

Comment: Also, what is `Choices()` for construct?

Comment: Sorry, `Choices()` is from `django-model-utils` (https://pypi.org/project/django-model-utils/)!

Comment: Have you tried to use what I suggested but w/ `MultipleChoiceField` (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#multiplechoicefield) instead of `ChoiceField`?